# Prove that $\int_X(f+g)\;d\mu=\int_Xf\;d\mu+\int_X g\;d\mu$ for an extended $\mu$-integrable function.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I have doubts in proving the linearity of the integral in the case of extended $\mu$-integrable function.
Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, then a measurable  function $f\colon X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that at least one of the $\int f_+\;d\mu$ and $\int f_-\;d\mu$ is finite is said an extended $\mu$.integrable function. We remember that $f_+=\max\{f, 0\}$ and $f_-=\max\{-f, 0\}$.

**Theorem** Let $f$ be a extended $\mu$-integrable function on $X$ and finite a.e.; let $g\in L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Then $f+g$
is an extendend $\mu$-integrable function and $$\int_X(f+g)\;d\mu=\int_Xf\;d\mu+\int_X g\;d\mu$$

*Proof.* We suppose that $$\int_X f_+\;d\mu <\infty,\quad \int_X f_-\;d\mu=\infty.$$ We define $h:=f+g$, then we have $$h_+-h_-=(f_+-f_-)+(g_+-g_-).\tag1$$ Now, since $g\in L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, we have that $g_{\pm}\in L^1(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and therefore are finite a.e. Furthermore, since $f$ is finite almost everywhere, also $f_{\pm}$ is finite almost everywhere.

> **Question.** From $(1)$ can I obtain $(2)$? And if yes, why? My answer is yes, but I'm not sure if you need to that $h$ is finite almost everywhere.

If yes, we have that

$$h_++f_-+g_-=h_-+f_++g_+\quad\text{a.e in}\quad X.\tag2$$

Then necessarily from the equality just written we deduce that $$\int_X h_-\;d\mu =\infty.$$

Since $h_+\le f_++g_+$ a.e. in $X$ results that $h_+\in L^1$ and so $$\int_X h\;d\mu=-\infty.$$ Since $$\int_X f\;d\mu =-\infty, \int_X |g|\; d\mu<\infty$$ we have done.

Comment: The answer to  Question 1 is obviously yes. Make an attempt to self-answer Question 2 in a similar fashion.

Comment: @NatMath consider that $f^+\leq |f|$ and so $\mu(f^+=\infty)\leq \mu(|f|=\infty)$

Comment: @SnoopThanks! I have a last question for you. To arrive at equality $(1)$ one must deal with numbers, otherwise it could happen that $h_+(x)=+\infty$ and $h_-(x)=0$. What guarantees the $h_+(x)$ and $h_-(x)$ are numbers?

Comment: Hint: all summands in equation (1) are in $[0,+\infty]\,.$ Do we need them to be finite?

Comment: You may want to number all your equations. $h_+-h_-=(f_+-f_-)+(g_+-g_-)$ looks OK and you showed that all the ingredients of (1) are finite a.e. Then ?

Comment: You can because you need (1) only a.e. In other words: the points of $X$ were we run into $\infty-\infty$ problems we simply ignore. They are a set of measure zero.

Comment: You showed $h_+\le f_++g_+\,.$ Likewise $h_-\le f_-+g_-\,.$ What can you now say a bout $h_+,h_-\,?$

Comment: No. You can show $h_+\le f_++g_+$ directly. This was originally a Question 2 which you removed. And I asked you in my very first comment to address that question. A very unconcentrated post I must say. Better to think about it deeply and reconvene if necessary tomorrow.

Comment: Regardless what we discussed about (1) and (2) it won't help to fix your proof. In its first line you wrote "Suppose $\int_X f_-\,d\mu=\infty\,.$" Was $f$ not assumed to be integrable? That's all pretty messy and I recommend to study in the literature a proof of this well-known theorem. ***Case closed***

Comment: @KurtG.Darling, the case will close when I understand. If you had read the post carefully you would have understood that it is not the standard case where both functions $f$ and $g$ are integrable, but it is the case where the function f is exetend $\mu$ integrable whose definition is cleary written.

Comment: I see. Still wondering what all that trouble with $h_+$ and (1) and (2) was.

Answer (score 1):

***Lemma.*** We have $h_+\le f_++g_+$ and $h_-\le f_-+g_-\,.$

*Proof.* By definition
$$
h_+=\max(h,0)=\max(f+g,0)\,.
$$
When $f+g\le 0$ then $h_+=0\le f_++g_+\,.$ When $f+g>0$ then $f_+>0$ or $g_+>0\,.$ Since $f\le f_+$ and $g\le g_+$ we get $h_+=f+g\le f_++g_+\,.$ This shows the claim for  $h_+\,.$

Since $h_-=(-h)_+$ the claim for $h_-$ follows from application to $-h=-f-g\,.$
\begin{align}\tag*{$\Box$}
\phantom{\quad}
\end{align}
***Proof of the Theorem:*** When $f$ is extended $\mu$-integrable then at least one of the integrals
$$
\textstyle\int_Xf_+\,d\mu\,,\quad \int_Xf_-\,d\mu\,
$$
is finite.
Since $g$ is integrable, both integrals
$$
\textstyle\int_Xg_+\,d\mu\,,\quad \int_Xg_-\,d\mu\,
$$
are finite.

By the Lemma
\begin{align}
\textstyle\int_Xh_+\,d\mu&\le\textstyle\int_Xf_+\,d\mu+\int_Xg_+\,d\mu\,,\\[4mm]
\textstyle\int_Xh_-\,d\mu&\le\textstyle\int_Xf_-\,d\mu+\int_Xg_-\,d\mu\,.
\end{align}
Therefore at least one of the integrals
$$
\textstyle\int_Xh_+\,d\mu\,,\quad \int_Xh_-\,d\mu
$$
is finite. That is: $h$ is extended $\mu$-integrable.

By definition of $h=f+g$ and of $h_\pm,f_\pm,g_\pm$ we have
$$
h_+-h_-=f_+-f_-+g_+-g_-\,.
$$
Only three cases are possible:

***Case I.*** $\int_Xh_+\,d\mu=+\infty$ and $\int_Xf_+\,d\mu=+\infty$ and all
other integrals of $h_-,f_-,g_+,g_-$ are finite. Then
$$
\textstyle\underbrace{\int_Xh\,d\mu}_{+\infty}=\underbrace{\int_Xf\,d\mu}_{+\infty}+\underbrace{\int_Xg_\,d\mu}_{\in(-\infty,\infty)}\,.
$$
***Case II.*** $\int_Xh_-\,d\mu=+\infty$ and $\int_Xf_-\,d\mu=+\infty$ and all
other integrals of $h_+,f_+,g_+,g_-$ are finite. Then
$$
\textstyle\underbrace{\int_Xh\,d\mu}_{-\infty}=\underbrace{\int_Xf\,d\mu}_{-\infty}+\underbrace{\int_Xg_\,d\mu}_{\in(-\infty,\infty)}\,.
$$
***Case III.*** All integrals are finite. This case is trivial.